# how to get fetch value in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

```
        $map=$this->Sessiondetails->find("all");    
        $this->set("map",$map);
    foreach($map as $maps){ 
   echo $maps['Sessiondetails']['latitude'];
    }
```

I want to fetch only 3rd row values . How to do it in cakephp. I am using cakephp 2x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you do it in SQL? Think about it and then use cake syntax

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#retrieving-your-data

```
$map = $this->Sessiondetails->find(
    "all"
    array(
        'offset' => 2
        'limit' => 1
    )
);
```

of course if you want to run a query that retrieves all the records but then  just show the 3rd record you can simply do

```
echo $map[2]['Sessiondetails']['latitude']
```

Comment: I don't understand your request. Try to better explain your needs

Comment: foreach($map as $maps){ 
   echo $maps['Sessiondetails']['latitude'];
    }. I ll get all values here .. i want to fetch only 3rd value of that foreach loop.

Comment: Well, it's basic array manipulation. Just `echo $map[2]['Sessiondetails']['latitude']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2way

If you use Paginator component you can use this :

```
$this->paginate = array('limit' => 10);

else : 

$map = $this->Sessiondetails->find(
    "all",
    array(
        'offset' => 2
        'limit' => 1
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, Here you just need to pass the limit..

```
<?php 
$map=$this->Sessiondetails->find("all",array('limit'=>'2,1'););    
$this->set("map",$map);
foreach($map as $maps)
{ 
   echo $maps['Sessiondetails']['latitude'];
}
?>
```